# Should security headers/policies be set in nginx or express?

Tags: node.js, security, express, nginx, http-headers

What is the best practice when it comes to setting security policies such as CSP and http security headers such as HSTS? Should they be configured within my express.js application? Or is it best practice to configure them in nginx? I found documents on how to implement them but I am not sure where they should be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Either could be used. You should put them where it's most appropriate for you and really depends on your set up.

I'm assuming you have an Nginx web server in front of one or more NodeJs application servers?

If so, then are some pages returned from Nginx (e.g. static pages) and some from Node (e.g. dynamic)? Do you have more than one Node server?

It also depends what you are doing with Node. It's quite common to have Nginx return HTML, CSS and Javascript and then use that Javascript to make AJAX calls to a node server to return JSON data. As CSP is needed on the HTML document and not tele JSON it makes no sense to return CSP headers from Node in this scenario.

Some headers like HSTS are set for whole domain so, to me, it makes sense to set them at the Nginx layer so they affect all requests - static pages served by Nginx and dynamic pages served by one or more Node servers. This also means you don't have to remember to set them if you ever set up another node server as well.

However if different data is returned for each service and/or request it may make sense to do that in Node. For example if your Node application needs to be able to set different CORS headers differently based on the request coming in, then it makes no sense to do this in Nginx and try to repeat the logic based on request URL and parameter.

Ultimately you should decide to do it where it makes most sense based on application set up, where its most likely to be set correctly (so it's not set when it shouldn't it set to wrong value and also so it's not too easy to forget to set it in future) and where it makes most sense to manage it (e.g. sometimes it's easier to change application code than server config or vice versa).

Comment: That's correct. I have an nginx server in front of 4 node servers. Some pages are returned by nginx and some from node. I am finding that if I configure the secure attribute on cookies within express, it is not taking effect. 
```
  app.enable('trust proxy');
  app.use(session({
    store: cache,
    secret: config.session.secret,
    cookie: {
      // secure: true,
      // proxy: true,
      maxAge: config.session.maxAge
    }
  }));
```
This is what I have set in express.

Comment: Sounds like a separate issue and perhaps you're not setting this secure cookie right in node/express. So would raise a separate question for this.